# javascript comma operator in java

Tags: java, javascript, math

I'm trying to convert the following javascript to java

```
var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
          Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                 Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

it's all fairly simple except I'm unsure what the comma after cos(lat1) does?
I read that in javascript it is used to assign the value after the coma to a variable while still evaluating the first expression, although in the above code the expression before the comma is not stored?

Any help on converting this to java or understanding what the comma does?

The original maths formula also has a comma

```
φ2 = asin( sin(φ1)*cos(d/R) + cos(φ1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ) )
 λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin(θ)*sin(d/R)*cos(φ1), cos(d/R)−sin(φ1)*sin(φ2) )
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not an operator, it's simply separating the two arguments to `atan2`.  It's [exactly the same](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) in Java.

(Recall that `atan2` takes the `x` and `y` components separately, in order to resolve rotational ambiguity.)

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that, more coffee required!

Comment: @drunkmonkey or less coffee and more sleep :)

Answer (score 4):

`Math.atan2` method accepts two arguments. Comma simply separates it.

> **Math.atan2(y, x)**
>
> Returns the arctangent of the quotient of its arguments.

**Reference:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2

Answer (score 1):

The only change required is to give the variables a type.

```
double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d / R) +
        Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(d / R) * Math.cos(brng));
double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(d / R) * Math.cos(lat1),
        Math.cos(d / R) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2));
```